Installing an Icon theme with tweaks broke my applications
I’ve installed an icon theme with elementary-tweaks and I am now unable to access majority of my apps including the files manager, terminal, or any sort of settings. This is a similar situation to another problem I’ve seen on this forum except I’m not able to access the terminal.

elementary-tweaks is no longer supported, and has not been for 4 years or so. Use pantheon-tweaks please https://flathub.org/apps/io.github.pantheon_tweaks.pantheon-tweaks
